# LC filter stepper motor

Tags: motor, filter, stepper-motor, passive-networks

can i use lc filter on three phase stepper motor (variable reluctance motor) to get sinewave current ?
We know that if we put sinewave voltage on ststor windings, the stator current will not be sinewave shape due to variable reluctance of the stepper motor.

Lets assume the input voltage is :

1 PWM pulses voltage.
2 Normal 50/60 Hz sinewave voltage.

Thanks.

Comment: Vague question. What are you wishing to accomplish with a LC Circuit?

Comment: sinewave current . at least very close to sinewave current.

Comment: It's indeed unclear what you are asking.  Stepper motors typically require multiple offset phases to drive, however there is a technique of using a phase shift capacitor to run one from a single phase supply - the "SLO-SYN" brand popularized this.  Motors optimized for this would be different than those optimized for normal moderate voltage digital sequencer drivers.

Comment: You could use a PWM/filter for each phase, but why would you when there are integrated controllers that already do this using L/R filter approach.